# Ruby Mechanize manipulate dropdown with no name and no id

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I need to manipulate a webpage with Mechanize, but they've made it hard... I have no way of accessing elements I need to manipulate via conventional means.

The scenario is I want to select an element from the dropdown, then hit the login button.

Here is my HTML:

```
<body style="background-color:white;">
<div class="alert-login-place-holder"></div>
<div class="container">
    <h2 style="color: #1ab394;"><span style="color: black;">MAX  </span>- X1 Menu Console - <span style="color: black;">Login</span>
    </h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 b-r" style="border-right: 2px solid #e7eaec;">

            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <p>Select Your Identity Provider:</p>
                <select class="form-control partner-select" style="font-size: 12px;width: 300px;">
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <p>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary login-button" href="#" role="button" onclick="handlePartnerLogin()"
                       style="width:15%">GO</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->


</div>

</body>
```

Here is my ruby code:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

#Make it where I can hit https...
agent.agent.http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

#Go to the login page
page = agent.get("my_url_that_I_figure_I_shouldnt_share")

#Grab the select and choose option

form = Mechanize::Form.new page.at('body'), agent
print form.class
print page.body
form.field_with(:class => 'form-control partner-select').options[1].click
```

It doesn't work as field_with requires :id or :name. I have neither. I can get the element in itself via .search... but then how do I manipulate it within the form? This is a real pain... and it's a shame as there are a lot of elements I have to contact that are similarly not addressable via name or id...

Comment: There's no form there. Maybe just do a `Mechanize#post`.

Comment: @pguardiario Your correct - no form. And further, a lot of the stuff I want to select is dynamically populated via JS. I had to go with selenium webdriver to suit my needs, in this case.